# Best way to automatically create different process names for qsub

Tags: qsub

I am running my program on a high-performance computer, usually with different parameters as input. Those parameters are given to the program via a parameter file, i.e. the qsub-file looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N <job-name>
#PBS -A <name>
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=20:mpiprocs=20
#PBS -l walltime=80:00:00
#PBS -M <mail-address>
#PBS -m bea 
module load foss

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

mpirun main parameters.prm

# Append the job statistics to the std out file
qstat -f $PBS_JOBID
```

Now usually I run the same program multiple times more or less at the same time, with different `parameter.prm`-files. Nevertheless they all show up in the job-list with the same name, making the correlation between the job in the list and the used parameters difficult (not impossible).
Is there a way to change the name of the program in the job list dynamically, depending on the used input parameters (ideally from within `main`)? Or is there another way to change the job name without having to edit the job-file every time I run

```
qsub job_script.pbs
```

?
Would be a solution to create a shell script which reads data from the parameter file, and then in turn creates the job-script and runs it? Or are there easier ways?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `-N` option on the command line:

`qsub -N job1 job_script.pbs`

You can then use a for loop to iterate over the `*.prm` files:

```
for prm in *.prm
do
  prmbase=$(basename $prm .prm)
  qsub -N $prmbase main $prm
done
```

This will name each job by the parameter file name, sans the `.prm` suffix.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can not test it anymore, due to the switch from pbs to slurm on our HPC cluster...

Comment: Is there a way to use the -v to name the job?